# Banner Serving Optimization

Tags: php, banner, banner-ads

Like most of the pages, my website have multiple banners in a single page.

We have an internal banner system.For calling a banner, a web request is made like

```
/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=top&userid=1
/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=bottom&userid=1
/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=center&userid=1
/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=left&userid=1
```

All these request goes to different(internal) server, which is handled by me.

For optimizing:
i planned to call request like

```
/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=top,bottom,center,left&userid=1
```

and from page where its getting called, i will manuplate the resuls. Hence the http requests will go down.

Questions:

1. Any other approach will be better ?
2. Should i create a wrapper which accepts request like 
   `/bannersystem/?page=home&subpage=top,bottom,center,left&userid=1` and from the wrapper calling the old url internally to avoid code changes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. Are you sure you need to optimize? Did you measure current performances?

Let's say you did. :)

What kind of optimization? speed? bandwith consumption? both?

Did you enable compression on your banner system to minimize bandwidth consumption and transfer time?

Your approach seems good enough, by doing a unique request instead of four. But you should probably rewrite the code instead of calling the old urls. I don't know, maybe your code is fast enough and you may not need it.

Comment: Reducing http requets is gd i  guess ?

Comment: Let's assume it is. If you didn't measure the actual performances, how do you know it is worth the effort?